# controls size when i maximize my application

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

- I'm using C# WPF for my application and I'm working to make my application simple (not crowded) with controls in UI.
- when I started my project using the default size of windows it was good looking, with a good space around controls and panels to make eyes comfortable.
- The trouble begin when I maximize my application to fit screen size. Controls and panels stretch so much and become so large to fit the screen.
- I tried to use **Min width** and **Max width** properties but when I maximize I find application located in center. In size I explicit and wide empty space around it.
- I tried to use a standard dimensions **1024x768** but I faced the same trouble. Empty space that should be filled with more controls.
- How can I make my application fit to any screen without seeing that much space appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just wrap the lot in a `ViewBox`

Example:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Class="WpfApplication13.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" x:Name="UI" Width="459" Height="293"  >
    <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
        <Grid Width="1024" Height="768" >
            <All your content .....
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</Window>
```